# Is it possible to make Zybo board work from SD card configuration only with bit file?

Tags: verilog, fpga, zynq

I'm newbie to Zynq especially Zybo-board.
I want to turn on  the onboard LED light through original configured bit file.

BecauseI have no JTAG cable, the following question is come up with.
Is it possible to make Zybo board work from SD card configuration only with bit file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a boot.bin file containing the FPGA bitstream, which you store on a FAT32 partition on the SD card.
http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Prepare+boot+image
Most instructions assume you would also like to run SW, but it is not necessary. You might actually need a fsbl.elf file, which is created by the SDK included with Vivado, but I am not sure if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

in a Zynq device the CPU always boots first, then the FPGA. That means a first stage boot loader is needed to boot the CPU, grab the bitstream from SD-card and program the FPGA.

You can use the Zynq FSBL application template to generate the FSBL.elf. Generate the boot.BIN (which is a combination of the FSBL and Bitstream in one file). Also set the jumper on your Zybo board to boot from SD-card.